# Wampserver 2.2 PHP version 5.4.3, Apache 2.4.2 and MySql 5.5.24

Tags: wamp

I have been searching for Wampserver 2.2 (with PHP version 5.4.3, Apache 2.4.2 and MySql 5.5.24) all day, I want this specific version because its the only one that runs on my computer without errors, please can someone direct me to a link where I can download it. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After hard work Ive found these two for you:

[WampServer 32bit version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202/WampServer%202.2/wampserver2.2e/wampserver2.2e-php5.4.3-httpd2.2.22-mysql5.5.24-32b.exe/download)
**Specs:**
php 5.4.3
Apache 2.2.22
Mysql 5.5.24

[WampServer 64bit version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202/WampServer%202.2/wampserver2.2e/wampserver2.2e-php5.4.3-httpd-2.4.2-mysql5.5.24-x64.exe/download)
**Specs:**
php 5.4.3
Apache 2.4.2
Mysql 5.5.24